# TeamCity (build runner requirement)

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm new with TeamCity and I have a problem when I'm trying to build project with CMake.
I downloaded CMake plugin and successful installed it. So now I have in *Build step*: CMake Build and CMake configure. For my project I choosed CMake build. In properties I didn't change something so there're ini params. I clicked *Run* and had message:

> Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration. Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration requirements.

I have only 1 agent. It's connected and enabled. In Build Queue in field *Compatible agents* I see that my agent is incomplatible. What can I do with that?:C

Comment: Please can you post any messages you see on the `Compatible Agents` tab of the build configuration?

Comment: @SteveChapman thanks for your response:) I've just done with  reinstall TeamCity and my agent is connected now:) Think there was problem with installation:C